# How to make Server and client sockets work on public ip on mobile?

Tags: sockets, networking, social-networking, mobile-application, application-server

I am working on an application that uses socket to transfer data from one device to other without the server interference and it is important that no one can get a copy of the data only the sender and the receiver. The server will be only for certificate authority and ip addresses collection and distribution. The main issue was opening a connection between to devices and it was solved by configuring the router to accept outside connection and port for warding and so on .. yet i am building the application for users that wont bother themselves to configure there owb routers .. I am asking for a solution to the problem or a better way to set the communication between the devices.

Answer (score 0):

I search the internet for more details on the subject and i found other solution is to use P2P. There are few P2P platform like jxta or sip2peer. that can reach the client even if the client is behind a fire wall and this solve the problem. instead of using java for android or swift for ios, i will use xamarin (C#) to do that, since xamarin is native cross platform IDE .. thanks to every body in this greet community.